# How can I read the X11 clipboard from a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard, x11

I'm working on a JavaFX application and I would like to support pasting text via middle mouse button in an X11 environment.

Is there a way to access the content of the X11 clipboard in Java/JavaFX?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [`javafx.scene.input.Clipboard`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html) - *"Represents an operating system clipboard, on which data may be placed during, for example, cut, copy, and paste operations."*?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yes: it's not the one I want ;-) X11 desktop environments tend to have two clipboards: one that gets filled by selecting some text somewhere, the other one needs a copy event (something like Ctrl+C). The Clipboard class seems to handle only the latter, I want the former.

Comment: Given the specialty nature, I would say the immediate answer would be no as the API would be trying to follow the path of least resistance/lowest common denominator, but it's not my area of expertise...

Comment: That's not clipboard, that's selection. Have no idea about JavaFX; in old skool Java that would be `sun.awt.X11.XSelection`.

Comment: I also have this problem - Unix mouse clipboard does not work, not for copying text by selecting it and not for pasting by clicking the scroll mouse button

Comment: Related question: [JavaFX: Mouse clipboard does not work in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032290/javafx-mouse-clipboard-does-not-work-in-unix).

Answer (score 2):

To access X11 selection clipboard:

Required imports:

```java
import sun.awt.X11.XClipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
```

Code:

```java
XClipboard xClipboard = new XClipboard("Selection", "PRIMARY");
// Set value:
xClipboard.setContents(new StringSelection("Hello"), null);
// Read value:
String stored = xClipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
```

The important note is the values `Selection` and `PRIMARY`, as if you write:

```java
clipboard = new XClipboard("System", "CLIPBOARD");
```

you will be reading the system clipboard instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to this 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088117 there is no way to access Selection with JavaFX.

Bug report

> Using JavaFX-8 with Java8u45 on SUSE11, there is no possibility to copy/paste using mouse selection or using a click on the scroll. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032290/javafx-mouse-clipboard-does-not-work-in-unix

Answer

> Lowering the priority to P4. I note that this is more of an unimplemented feature than a bug (it has never been supported in FX). We will look at it for JDK 9.
>   Workaround: use copy/paste (CTRL-C / CTRL-V)