# JavaFX: Mouse clipboard does not work in Unix

Tags: java, javafx-8, clipboard

In Unix, as you probably know, it is common to use the mouse for copy-paste operations. I.e. **text selection** automatically copies it to the clipboard and **clicking on the scroll** pastes it where you click.

I do not have clipboard problems with GUI applications that use Java 7 with Swing.

But in JavaFX with Java 8 (update 45), the mouse clipboard does not work, so that:

- I cannot paste any text to the GUI by clicking the scroll
- I cannot copy any text from the GUI by just selecting it

I encountered this problem with `TextInputDialog` and with `TextArea`. I haven't tried other widgets so far.

Can you please tell how to enable the mouse clipboard?

**Screenshots:**

[image: TextInputDialogScreenshot]

[image: TextAreaScreenshot]

Comment: Related question: [How can I read the X11 clipboard from a JavaFX application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21844255/873282)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I would like to help with your own code but I did not see any so I have an example of something I did.

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction21(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            ObservableList<Part> rowList = table2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

            final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

            content.putString(rowList.get(0).getPartNumber());
            Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
    }
```

this is an event listener for a context menu item.

Basically you would have to control the context menu and then get the `SystemClipboard` and set the text in there

Answer (score 1):

In the moment there is no supported way to do this with JDK.
The bug/feature request is listed here 
[OpenJDK bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088117]
It backlinks now to this SO entry.

@user4231709 Sorry, your solution doesn't help with the problem because this uses the system clipboard which is different.
For further reading look for "sun.awt.X11.XSelection".

There is also another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844255/how-can-i-read-the-x11-clipboard-from-a-javafx-application) entry about this topic.